# How to read / determine / check the foreground color of pipeline output?

Tags: powershell

## Question

I would like to suppress Yellow host output. How, if at all, can I do the following?

```
some-cli.exe | Where-Object { $_.ForegroundColor -ne Yellow }
```

The `$_.ForegroundColor -ne Yellow` is not supported. What, if anything, is supported?

The `some-cli.exe` could be anything that produces multicolored output. For instance, it could be `choco`, `nuget`, `msbuild`...

Comment: Suppress yellow host output from what? (And why?)

Comment: Setting `$WarningPreference` to `SilentlyContinue` doesn't work?

Comment: Setting `$WarningPreference = "SilentlyContinue"` does not suppress the warning messages. @Bill_Stewart

Comment: It seems like your approach is backwards (the warnings should be disabled on the output side, not the filtering side). I would check if the command you're running has a configuration setting of some kind (command-line parameter?) that can suppress the warning messages you don't want to see. Other than that I don't have any other suggestions.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Agreed. The approach is backward. This is a hack thru and thru. I do appreciate the help. Unfortunately, `nuget.exe` does not have a setting to suppress only its package not found warning messages. Also, those warning messages are not PowerShell warnings - that's probably because `nuget.exe` works in both `cmd` and `posh`. I figured that PowerShell exposed a way to determine the `ForegroundColor` of pipeline text - thus, the hack approach emerged.

Comment: If they're not PowerShell warnings then of course `$WarningPreference` will not affect them...

Comment: Console applications can explicitly set the color used for console output, but unless they use ANSI terminal sequences for it (supported in the new W10 console only, so not many do) there is no way for hosts to detect it, whether PowerShell or anything else. NuGet appears to be particularly bad with options for configuring its output, either offering nothing at all, or command-specific flags that work only with MSBuild (like the `-Properties` of `nuget pack`). It has a whole array of warnings and errors that can be individually suppressed, but not when run independently...

Comment: ...in short, I think it might be worth taking the NuGet folks to task for the relatively poor experience for standalone command line use. And by that I mean throwing some [issues](https://github.com/nuget/home/issues) at the wall to see what sticks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible if the foreground color wasn't set in PowerShell itself (and the method of detection in this case escapes me anyway). When you assign the output of an external command which produces color output to a variable for later processing (this would extend to passing the output down the pipeline), the color information is lost. For example, if you have Chocolatey installed (this is one example program I know which produces colorized output) running:

```
$output = choco install -y nonexistent-package
$output
```

loses the color which is normally red for the error text provided by choco.exe.

> **Note:** As Jeroen pointed out in comments, "Console applications can explicitly set the color used for console output, but unless they use ANSI terminal sequences for it (supported in the new W10 console only, so not many do) there is no way for hosts to detect it, whether PowerShell or anything else."

---

However, based on your comments and specific use-case you should be able to pipe the output of `nuget restore` to a `Where-Object` clause and filter out any lines starting with `WARNING`:

```
nuget restore | Where-Object {
  $_ -notmatch '^WARNING'
}
```

I'm not sure if you tried filtering the way I showed above but based on your comment it sounds like perhaps all of the output might not be separated per line, but retrieved as a raw string for some reason. If that is the case you can make one modification for this to work, split the output on new lines:

```
( nuget restore ) -split "`r?`n" | Where-Object { ....
```

The downside to this approach is that if the warning spans multiple lines, it won't catch the subsequent line. The warning would have to be localized to one line for this to work.

Comment: I believe the way I've seen this done before requires the output color to have been set in PowerShell. When I run external commands which produce colored output and assign the output to a variable, the color information is lost.

Comment: I think you're right about the information being lost. The upstream tool producing the output is probably setting the host foreground color as a session variable, so to speak; in that case, I would somehow have to read `$Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor` before the tool resets the color.

Comment: This is something that might be possible with a homegrown PowerShell host but that would be overengineering at this point.

Comment: Given the additional context my answer contains a suitable workaround for your specific scenario which others may find useful if they are stonewalled by something similar when finding this question. As discussed on Meta in the past (I'm not digging up the specific question) you should not remove content from someone else's answer when it changes the intent, and the original poster reserves the right to roll back to their previous revision. I did include the comment which you provided from Jeroen, however, and moved the relevant information to the top.

Comment: It became relevant when you put the information about it in the question. I don't really think we need to argue about this, the correct information is at the top of the answer, and a context specific workaround is at the bottom for those inclined to indulge. All we've done is make the answer more useful than "you can't do this" by providing, "you can't always do this, but here's a suitable technique to workaround the limitation"

Comment: I appreciate that it was my mistake to include NuGet specific content in the question. I wish I had avoided that mistake, and I appreciate that it was *my* mistake not yours. What you include in your answer, obviously, is totally up to you, and you're right, the additional information might help people filter similar content in the future.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236620/discussion-between-bender-the-greatest-and-shaun-luttin).